# Finding Green's Function for a sphere domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to obtain the Green's function for a sphere domain. This work, will be easier to done by the method of images. In fact i need " Obtaining Green's function by the method of images"
Thank you all

Comment: Obtaining Green's function for a sphere by the method of images

Comment: You still haven't tell us what is the given ODE/PDEs? Also, it's difficult to tell if you know about the method of images or not.